# What is different in the manufacturing of differently rated MOSFETs?

Tags: cmos, nmos, manufacturing

The IRF540N is one of the MOSFETs I'm using, and the IRF510N. Both look exactly the same from the outside because they use the same packaging, but they are rated for different power levels.

For processors there are different manufacturing processes, like 5 nm or 12 nm. How many nm are generic power MOSFETs manufactured to?

I also noticed that digital circuits with nMOS and pMOS transistors don't show a parasitic body diode or body connection in their schematics, why is that?

If the only way of determining a MOSFET's power is its transistor size, and they can only reach a few MHz at medium currents, how much does CPU NMOS reach over a few GHz?

Comment: Power FETs are very different devices than logic FETs, so asking about logic nodes for a power fet doesn't make sense.  I'm not an expert in power electronics, but the Wikipedia article looks like it has a lot of detail on the differences. That might be a better place to start than asking someone here to explain to you what is a very lengthy topic.